# using if with eval("") in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, if-statement, repeater, eval

I am using repeater to display the news on the news section. In my news section i have got 2 labels(title, Description) and one image field. Below is the code which i am using to populate the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptNews" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="newsImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#String.format("../Images/News/{0}", Eval("newsImage")) %>' />
<asp:Label ID="newsTitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("newsTitle") %>'></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="newsDescription" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("newsDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
<br />
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to use if statement with the  , for instance if the Eval("newsImage") is null then i want to disable the image control and just show the title and description of news . Any suggestions on how to acheive this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

should be like... `Visible='<%# Eval("newsImage").ToString() != "Null" %>'`

```
<asp:Image ID="newsImage" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("newsImage").ToString() == "Null" %>'  ImageUrl='<%#String.Format("../Images/News/{0}", Eval("newsImage")) %>' />
```

Comment: the problem is i am saving Null on the database , if there is no image , therefore it returns a string null, so i want to check if the image string is null then visible=fale else show image

Comment: Edited the condition. plz check now.

Comment: i tried with the above code, now it doesnt show any images, even when there is a image for that news id

Comment: Sorry the condition is != rather ==, I have edited answer. just change the condition and it will work.

Comment: Eval("newsImage").ToString() !="Null"  .. tried using this it works but still its showing an empty img block for the news which have no image i dont want that

Comment: can you check your String , it is comparison string will case senstive. e.g NULL or null or Null, compare to particular value.

Comment: i dunno y it is saving in d database like : 'NULL'

Answer (score 1):

Add the Visible attribute to your Image tag:

```
   Visible="<%# Eval("newsImage") != null %>"
```

Although in such cases it might be better to use the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event, it's very easy to use.

Comment: the problem is i am saving Null on the database , if there is no image , therefore it returns a string null, so i want to check if the image string is null then visible=fale else show image

Comment: but this is exactly what you want. If `Eval("newsImage")` is null, then the Visible attribute will become "false" and you won't see the image. If it's not null, Visible will become "true" and you will see the image.

Comment: Eval("newsImage").ToString() =="Null" then visible= 'false' else visible="true"

Comment: Eval("newsImage").ToString() !="Null"  .. tried using this it works but still its showing an empty img block for the news which have no image i dont want that

Comment: When `Visible` is `false`, the control doesn't get to the client. It shouldn't exist in the response at all. Check if you have a div around it or something like that.